# How to Center Text inside an SVG Path

Tags: css, svg, cycle

I need some help, when I use svg to draw a cycle and put some text, how to Center Text inside an SVG Path

```html
 <svg height="500"width="500">
       <path d="M250 250 L250 0 A250,250,0,0,1,250,0  L250 250 Z"fill="#fff"stroke="#fff"></path>
       <defs>
          <path id="p0"d="M250 50 A200,200,0,0,1,250,50 Z"fill="#fff"stroke="#fff"></path>
       </defs>
       <text style="font-size: 24px;"x="0"text-anchor="center">
          <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"xlink:href="#p0">0test text</textPath>
       </text>
       <path d="M250 250 L250 0 A250,250,0,0,1,466.50635094610965,124.99999999999997  L250 250 Z"fill="#ddd"stroke="#ddd"></path>
       <defs>
          <path id="p1"d="M250 50 A200,200,0,0,1,423.2050807568877,149.99999999999997 Z"fill="#ddd"stroke="#ddd"></path>
       </defs>
       <text style="font-size: 24px;"x="0"text-anchor="center">
          <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"xlink:href="#p1">1test text</textPath>
       </text>
       <path d="M250 250 L466.50635094610965 124.99999999999997 A250,250,0,0,1,466.5063509461097,374.99999999999994  L250 250 Z"fill="#fff"stroke="#fff"></path>
       <defs>
          <path id="p2"d="M423.2050807568877 149.99999999999997 A200,200,0,0,1,423.20508075688775,349.99999999999994 Z"fill="#fff"stroke="#fff"></path>
       </defs>
       <text style="font-size: 24px;"x="0"text-anchor="center">
          <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"xlink:href="#p2">2test text</textPath>
       </text>
       <path d="M250 250 L466.5063509461097 374.99999999999994 A250,250,0,0,1,250.00000000000003,500  L250 250 Z"fill="#ddd"stroke="#ddd"></path>
       <defs>
          <path id="p3"d="M423.20508075688775 349.99999999999994 A200,200,0,0,1,250.00000000000003,450 Z"fill="#ddd"stroke="#ddd"></path>
       </defs>
       <text style="font-size: 24px;"x="0"text-anchor="center">
          <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"xlink:href="#p3">3test text</textPath>
       </text>
       <path d="M250 250 L250.00000000000003 500 A250,250,0,0,1,33.49364905389038,375.0000000000001  L250 250 Z"fill="#fff"stroke="#fff"></path>
       <defs>
          <path id="p4"d="M250.00000000000003 450 A200,200,0,0,1,76.7949192431123,350.0000000000001 Z"fill="#fff"stroke="#fff"></path>
       </defs>
       <text style="font-size: 24px;"x="0"text-anchor="center">
          <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"xlink:href="#p4">4test text</textPath>
       </text>
       <path d="M250 250 L33.49364905389038 375.0000000000001 A250,250,0,0,1,33.49364905389024,125.00000000000017  L250 250 Z"fill="#ddd"stroke="#ddd"></path>
       <defs>
          <path id="p5"d="M76.7949192431123 350.0000000000001 A200,200,0,0,1,76.79491924311219,150.0000000000001 Z"fill="#ddd"stroke="#ddd"></path>
       </defs>
       <text style="font-size: 24px;"x="0"text-anchor="center">
          <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"xlink:href="#p5">5test text</textPath>
       </text>
       <path d="M250 250 L33.49364905389024 125.00000000000017 A250,250,0,0,1,249.99999999999994,0  L250 250 Z"fill="#fff"stroke="#fff"></path>
       <defs>
          <path id="p6"d="M76.79491924311219 150.0000000000001 A200,200,0,0,1,249.99999999999994,50 Z"fill="#fff"stroke="#fff"></path>
       </defs>
       <text style="font-size: 24px;"x="0"text-anchor="center">
          <textPath xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"xlink:href="#p6">6test text</textPath>
       </text>
    </svg>
```

Comment: get the bounding box of the path, set the text x, y appropriately.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You are part of the way there, but you have made a few mistakes.

`text-anchor="center"` is wrong.  It should be `text-anchor="middle"`.

In addition, you should add `startOffset="50%"` to the `<textPath>` element to specify that the text should be centred on the half-way point of the path.

Finally you need to fix the path itself.  You need to remove the `Z` path command at the end of the path description. You only want the arc, not the return line back to the start of the arc.

```html
<svg height="500"width="500">
 
  <path d="M250 250 L250 0 A250,250,0,0,1,466.50635094610965,124.99999999999997  L250 250 Z" fill="#ddd" stroke="#ddd"></path>
  <defs>
    <path id="p1" d="M250 50 A200,200,0,0,1,423.2050807568877,149.99999999999997" fill="#ddd" stroke="#ddd"></path>
  </defs>
  <text style="font-size: 24px;">
    <textPath xlink:href="#p1" startOffset="50%" text-anchor="middle">1test text</textPath>
  </text>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: what if I need to add the text outside the path like this image https://ibb.co/FsY5PPR

Comment: @AhmedElMetwallyJust point the <taxtPath path>` at the same shape that is displayed. https://jsfiddle.net/k0h1r5nq/

Comment: @AhmedElMetwally Try the baseline-shift attribute.

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  `<svg version="1.1" baseProfile="full" width="500" height="500" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

 <path id="1" fill="none" stroke="black" d="M 0 250 L 250 250"></path>
 <text>
  <textPath href="#1" text_anchor="middle" startOffset="50%" baseline-shift="10px">not centered</textPath>
 </text>

</svg>
`https://imgur.com/slEn5xs

Comment: @ROMS `text_anchor` is wrong. It should be `text-anchor`.

Answer (score 6):

Here I place the six texts on a path. The path is a full circle (arc) with the length (`pathLength`) of 12. Zero is at 12 o'clock. First `startOffset` is then 1, and so forth. The text is anchored in the middle. The "pizza slices" is made from a `<circle>` that is masked. The mask is made of three `<rect>`s that are skewed and rotated.

This is as clean as it can get.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" height="500" width="500">
  <defs>
    <path id="p1" d="M50 10 a 40 40 1 1 0 1 0" pathLength="12" />
    <mask id="m1">
      <g transform="translate(50 50) rotate(15)">
        <rect id="r1" width="50" height="50" fill="white"
          transform="skewX(15) skewY(15)" />
        <use href="#r1" transform="rotate(120)"/>
        <use href="#r1" transform="rotate(240)"/>
      </g>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="#ddd" mask="url(#m1)"/>
  <text font-size="6" text-anchor="middle">
    <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="1" side="right">1test text</textPath>
    <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="3" side="right">2test text</textPath>
    <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="5" side="right">3test text</textPath>
    <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="7" side="right">4test text</textPath>
    <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="9" side="right">5test text</textPath>
    <textPath href="#p1" startOffset="11" side="right">6test text</textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use text-anchor property with value of middle for example :

```html
<svg width="250" height="250">
  <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" fill="#aeaeae" />
  <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" fill="white" font-size="100px" font-family="Arial" dy=".3em">BC</text>
Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

Comment: This places text at the center of the `<svg>` element, **not** the center of the *path* (as the OP asked).

Answer (score 1):

It should be `text-anchor="middle"`. In addition, you should add `startOffset="50%"` to the `<textPath>` element to specify that the text should be centred on the half-way point of the path.